# Android setWebChromeClient not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

I am trying to load a website in the webview, but when I open the app, it doesn't load anything, instead it opens the link in the default browser.. How can I make it load in my webview? The code has no errors in eclipse but it doesn't do what it should.. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.example.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // find the WebView by name in the main.xml of step 2
        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

        // Enable javascript
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

        // Set WebView client
        browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        // Load the webpage
        browser.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set custom `WebViewClient`:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    });
```

`WebChromeClient` let you handle `JavaScript` functions.

`WebViewClient` let you handle loading page (`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`) and complete loading page (`onPageFinished()`).

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is called for subframes with non-https schemes. If you go to a a page like http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet your code will end up calling view.loadUrl('tel:1234') and you will end up showing an error page, since the webview doesn't know how to load a tel: URL. You should just return false from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`